# Get data by a specific query in a cassandra keyspace

Tags: cassandra, request, cqlsh

I have a cassandra table with this following scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace1.records (
    name text,
    sensor_id text,
    record_hour timestamp,
    record_time timestamp,
    raw_value text,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((name, sensor_id, record_hour), record_time)
)
```

I want to get from the records, how many records each sensor has every hour.
example:

```
sensor_id 145 has 3 records at 2016-10-13 10:00:00+0000
sensor_id 145 has 12 records at 2016-10-13 12:00:00+0000
sensor_id 227 has 4 records at 2016-10-14 20:00:00+0000
sensor_id 227 has 7 records at 2016-10-14 17:00:00+0000
sensor_id 227 has 2 records at 2016-10-14 08:00:00+0000
```

When I do a request like this when trying to get all records of one capture :

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace1.records WHERE sensor_id='145' ;
```

I get this error :

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Partition key parts: name must be restricted as other parts are"
```

and when I tried this query I got a result but not what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace1.records WHERE sensor_id = '145' AND name = 'client_NYC' AND record_hour IN ('2016-07-16 17:00:00+0000',  '2016-07-16 22:00:00+0000') ;
```

But my problem is I don't want to specify the name nor the record time in the request, I only want to know how many records a sensor has in a day every hour.

How to do that ? what is the right query in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to specify all the partition key when querying.**

You have specified `name, sensor_id, record_hour` as partition key, So every time you query you have specify all of these field.

If you just want the every hour count of record for each `sensor_id`, it is best to create a counter table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE record_count(
    sensor_id text,
    record_hour timestamp,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, record_hour)
);
```

Every time a record inserted into records, increment the value of count :

```
UPDATE record_count SET count = count + 1 WHERE sensor_id = ? AND record_hour = ?
```

Now you can get the record count by hour for each sensor

```
SELECT * FROM record_count WHERE sensor_id = ?
```

If you already have data on records and you want these data to be in your counter table, then you can use driver pagination to scan all the row and increment the counter.

Check this [Python Driver Pagination](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html#paging-large-queries)

Or Use Copy command to dump sensor_id and record_hour

```
COPY records (sensor_id , record_hour ) TO 'records.csv';
```

Now just for each line of `records.csv` append `,1` at the end of line and write to another file say `record_count.csv`.Now you have the csv, you can just import it.

```
COPY record_count (sensor_id , record_hour , count) FROM 'record_count.csv';
```

Comment: That's a very good idea, but records are being inserted in a massive way, so how can I make the count updates automatically ? and how can I fill the new table with the old data from the other table?

Comment: @Somar Which Cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: I use version 3.0.10

Comment: What about using a view?

Comment: Yes, you can use materialized view. But it will take much more storage than counter and count query will be slower

Comment: If you use counter table then  For older data you have to write code, to migrate these data to counter.

Comment: I can use python driver to fill the counter table, but I'm gonna need the same impossible queries ...